# if([labelView.layer containsPoint:touchPoint]) not working in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Can anyone tell that,  i have taken draggable label with `UIPangesture` when dragging and releasing mouse i am finding touch point using

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [panGesture locationInView:self.view];
```

now i want to check on which label is this label dragged.For this i am using this code

```
for(UILabel *labelView in self.view.subviews){
    if ([labelView isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint ));

        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(labelView.layer.frame));

        if([labelView.layer containsPoint:touchPoint]){

            int i=[[labelView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] tag];

            NSLog(@">>>> %d",i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how hard it is to properly indent the code, at-least when you want someone to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

panGesture passed to the gesture handler method has property 'view' that points which UILabel object you've setup with the recognizer

**EDIT:**
**-- the answe above was wrong. Thanks Jacky for pointing me out --**

self.view's hitTest:withEvent: method would return the view at the point. Pass nil to withEvent:

if self.view has subviews other than UILabel too and you want to avoid one of those returned, call

```
bool CGRectContainsPoint (
   CGRect rect,
   CGPoint point
);
```

for each label. Pass frame for rect, touchpoint for point

```
for(UILabel *labelView in self.view.subviews){
    if ([labelView isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(labelView.frame,touchPoint)){
            int i=[[labelView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] tag];
            NSLog(@">>>> %d",i);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The reason why .layer's  containsPoint: didn't work:

> thePoint A point in the receiver’s coordinate system.

In your code, touchPoint is in self.view's coordinate system that is different from any label's coordinate system

Comment: He wants to know which `UILabel`he is touching now with the `UILabel` he has ended dragging...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying.
This worked for me

```
if ([labelView.layer containsPoint:[labelView.layer convertPoint:touchPoint fromLayer:labelView.layer.superlayer]] == TRUE)
```

but your answer is also correct i have check that.